# Pass string from UserForm to website field using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am new to the use of VBA for web interactions.

I have a UserForm ("`FrmResults`") with a textbox ("`TxtSql`"). I am trying to use VBA to open a website and paste the text from the textbox to a textarea on this website.

So far I have the following code but this always starts the Debugger at the last piece, i.e. where I am trying to set the value of the textarea - even if I just use "test" for testing. I also tried using `.InnerHtml` instead of `.Value` but this fails as well.

**It always stops after it has opened the website so it fails to paste the copied text from the clipboard there.**

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or missing here ?

**My code:**

```
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim varResults As New DataObject

    varResults.SetText TxtSql.Text
    varResults.PutInClipboard

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    MyURL = "myURL"

    IE.Navigate MyURL
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.busy
    DoEvents

    Wend

    With IE.Document
        .getElementById("Oracle_profile_sql").Value = varResults
'        .all("mapnow_button").Click
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will open "Google.com" (for my tests), and will put the value from "TextSql" `TextBox` (from the User_Form) in the "Search" textbar of the "Google" website.

In your case, use the line :
    `.getElementById("Oracle_profile_sql").Value = varResults.GetText(1)`

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim MyURL As String
    Dim varResults As New DataObject

    varResults.SetText TxtSql.Text
    varResults.PutInClipboard

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' tested with the "Search" in Google
    MyURL = "https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=pj2TWLrWFYTN8gf0uIaIBw&gws_rd=ssl" ' "myURL"

    IE.Navigate MyURL
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    With IE.Document
        .getElementById("lst-ib").Value = varResults.GetText(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks so much - this is great ! The .GetText(1) did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the site you are trying to access.
E.g., the element can be an array. Here is something, that will work:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim IE          As Object
    Dim MyURL       As String
    Dim varResults  As New DataObject
    Dim el          As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    MyURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

    IE.Navigate MyURL
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.busy
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
    Wend


    Set el = IE.Document.getElementById("search")(0)
    el.value = "TEST"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! If I use your code then the Debugger jumps to the second line from the bottom. The element is a normal textarea inside a div. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: @Mike - try again.